# How do I add extra "values" to a PayPal button

Tags: html

I have the following code, which works fine as is.  It shows the price at checkout, but I also need it to include a size in the description.  How do I add this extra value please?

EDIT: Also, would need to add different shipping costs depending on which size is ordered.

```
<form id="for-sale-form" target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin: 0px;">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@your-web-domain.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $artwork; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://your-web-domain.com/thanks-payment.htm">
 <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
 <input type="hidden" name="quanity" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

 <select name="amount">
  <option value="499.99">Large £499.99</option>
  <option value="49.99">Medium £49.99</option>
  <option value="4.99">Small £4.99</option>
 </select><br>

 <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF">
 <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
 <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" alt="Add to Cart">
 <img alt="" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/step-3/#link-useadvancedvariables

Comment: yea, I looked there first, but couldn't find what I needed, and a lot of it didn't make sense to me either.